# What method should I use to count instances of subclasses in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, instance, counter, uniqueidentifier

I would like to implement a counter that will generate a unique ID for every instances of classes (and subclasses).

At the moment I use this:

```js
class Item {
 constructor(type) {
  this.constructor.counter = (this.constructor.counter || 0) + 1;
  this.type = type || "item";
  this._id = this.type + "_" + this.constructor.counter;
  console.log(this.id);
 }
   
 get id() {
  return this._id;
 }
}

class SubItem extends Item {
 constructor() {
  super("sub_item");
 }
}

var test1 = new Item(); // <- "item_1"
var test2 = new Item(); // <- "item_2"
var test3 = new Item(); // <- "item_3"
var test4 = new Item(); // <- "item_4"
var test5 = new SubItem(); // <- "sub_item_5"
var test6 = new SubItem(); // <- "sub_item_6"
var test7 = new Item(); // <- "item_5"
var test8 = new Item(); // <- "item_6"
```

Do you see the problem? If I do it by instantiating a SubItem first, every is working correctly... But when I instantiate the "mother class" first, the counter is broken. Is there a way to solve this problem?

The behavior I am looking for is:

```
var test1 = new Item(); // <- "item_1" 
var test2 = new Item(); // <- "item_2" 
var test3 = new Item(); // <- "item_3" 
var test4 = new Item(); // <- "item_4" 
var test5 = new SubItem(); // <- "sub_item_1" 
var test6 = new SubItem(); // <- "sub_item_2" 
var test7 = new Item(); // <- "item_5" 
var test8 = new Item(); // <- "item_6"
```

Comment: I have edited the (now deleted) comment that you put on my answer directly into your question.  If that comment was incorrect, please edit it out your question or edit your question to actually state what your expected output is.  The answers that you have right now are operating under differing assumptions.

Comment: Why exactly is the current behaviour a problem? I would suggest not to (ab)use the instance UID for distinguishing subclasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `counter` property on the `SubItem` is *shadowing* the `counter` property on the `Item` class. So, when the following line runs:

```
this.constructor.counter = (this.constructor.counter || 0) + 1;
```

When the first `SubItem` is instantiated, the `this.constructor.counter` that is being *accessed* is the `counter` on `Item`, via prototypal inheritence. But then the assignment to `this.constructor.counter` assigns to the `counter` property *directly on the SubItem*. (so, further instantiations of `SubItem` will refer to the `counter` directly on `SubItem` rather than the parent class).

You might check to see if the `counter` property is *directly on the constructor* instead, via `hasOwnProperty`:

```js
class Item {
  constructor(type) {
    this.constructor.counter = ((this.constructor.hasOwnProperty('counter') && this.constructor.counter) || 0) + 1;
    this.type = type || "item";
    this._id = this.type + "_" + this.constructor.counter;
    console.log(this.id);
  }

  get id() {
    return this._id;
  }
}

class SubItem extends Item {
  constructor() {
    super("sub_item");
  }
}

var test1 = new Item(); // <- "item_1"
var test2 = new Item(); // <- "item_2"
var test3 = new Item(); // <- "item_3"
var test4 = new Item(); // <- "item_4"
var test5 = new SubItem(); // <- "sub_item_5"
var test6 = new SubItem(); // <- "sub_item_6"
var test7 = new Item(); // <- "item_5"
var test8 = new Item(); // <- "item_6"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!
I don't fully understand how your solution works though. hasOwnProperty method returns a boolean and the && is a logical operator. I don't see how this returns a natural number?

Comment: Nevermind... I found my answer here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Answer (score 0):

I think I would simply initialize the counter on both the parent and the subclass. I'm kind of on the fence, but I think it's clearer and simplifies the code in the constructor. This also lets the subclass control the starting point (not that I think that's super useful):

```js
class Item {
 constructor(type) {
        this.constructor.counter++;
        this.type = type || "item";
  this._id = this.type + "_" + this.constructor.counter;
  console.log(this.id);
 }
   
 get id() {
  return this._id;
 }
}
Item.counter = 0 // initialize

class SubItem extends Item {
 constructor() {
        super("sub_item");
 }
}
SubItem.counter = 0 // initialize

var test1 = new Item(); // <- "item_1"
var test2 = new Item(); // <- "item_2"
var test3 = new Item(); // <- "item_3"
var test4 = new Item(); // <- "item_4"
var test5 = new SubItem(); // <- "sub_item_5"
var test6 = new SubItem(); // <- "sub_item_6"
var test7 = new Item(); // <- "item_5"
var test8 = new Item(); // <- "item_6"
```

Comment: This solution work, but I'm trying to keep my code as DRY as possible...

Answer (score -1):

Put the unique ID outside the constructor and allow it to be scoped by all classes that will increment it.

```js
let INSTANCE_COUNT = 0;

class Item {
  constructor(type) {
    this.type = type || "item";
    this._id = `${this.type}_${INSTANCE_COUNT++}`;
    console.log(this.id);
  }

  get id() {
    return this._id;
  }
}

class SubItem extends Item {
  constructor() {
    super("sub_item");
  }
}

var test1 = new Item(); // <- "item_0"
var test2 = new Item(); // <- "item_1"
var test3 = new Item(); // <- "item_2"
var test4 = new Item(); // <- "item_3"
var test5 = new SubItem(); // <- "sub_item_4"
var test6 = new SubItem(); // <- "sub_item_5"
var test7 = new Item(); // <- "item_6"
var test8 = new Item(); // <- "item_7"
```

Comment: The behavior I am looking for is for the "sub_item" to start counting at 1 instead of following the "mother class" counter. If I instantiate "sub_item" first, everything is fine... It's when I instantiate the "item" class first that the counter breaks.